# Visual Studio 2005: build solution

Tags: visual-studio-2005

If I build a solution in VS2005, will the build go to both bin/Debug and bin/Release?  Or do I need to specify something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it only goes into what release you've specified VS to build under. There should be a dropdown in your standard toolbar that specifies whether it's Debug, Release or any other custom build configuration that you've specified.

In [this image](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/arashsichanie/images/719608/original.aspx&imgrefurl=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arash/archive/2006/08/25/719626.aspx&usg=__CJ4ObRdg22moWWc-Wbi78j61qvY=&h=616&w=785&sz=96&hl=en&start=140&zoom=1&tbnid=iSlXiGRK9QxO5M%3a&tbnh=160&tbnw=204&ei=6E5jTdjHAcfIcbXWiNgP&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dvs2005%2Bchange%2Bsolution%2Bconfiguration%26um%3D1%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26qscrl%3D1%26biw%3D1333%26bih%3D690%26tbs%3Disch:10%2C4583&um=1&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=825&vpy=193&dur=4026&hovh=199&hovw=253&tx=99&ty=84&oei=q05jTcWQNJCuvgOHs939BA&page=9&ndsp=15&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:140&biw=1333&bih=690) it's set to debug (from the red highlight on the top of the screenshot) so will by default go to bin\Debug.

Comment: In your image, it gives the option of which .NET version.  Why don't I have that?

Comment: It doesnt go to both at same time, either of the one, based on the settings.

Comment: @Craig it probably belongs to another toolbar. You do not need this for building in Debug vs Release.